# How to open a winform with different thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I want to do a simple "please wait, loading" style form for my app. In main form, I prepare a map and locations. These preparing gets some time while loading. So I want to create a new thread which will open a loading form on front of the main form to display "please wait, loading" string, may be an animated gif etc. But I could not do this.

I write that code below.

```
LoadingForm loadingFormInstance;

private void mainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     locationLoadingFormThread = new Thread(showLoadingForm);
     locationLoadingFormThread.Start();
}

void showLoadingForm() {
     try
        {
            loadingFormInstance.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exceptionText = String.Format("{0}:", ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(exceptionText);
        } 
    }
```

with this code loading form never displayed. What is wrong I did not understand. I do something wrong but I cuold not understand the wrong.

Or any correct offer to do "please wait, loading" style something.

Thanks.

Comment: The correct way is to decouple your time-intensive work from the GUI. Do not create multiple GUI threads, that's pretty much always the bad idea (and in fact, you're not even doing that - you'd have to run a new message loop on the new thread too). Once you've got the work in a separate thread (a background worker), you no longer have unresponsive UI and you can display your "Loading..." form and perhaps even support cancellation etc.

Comment: Windows forms application only can have one UI thread.

Comment: @Matt Well, that's not entirely true. It is definitely a bad idea to have more than a single UI thread, but it is doable.

Comment: @Luaan I object the "bad idea". It depends on circumstances.  I write apps ahving one window per monitor - and everyone on a separate UI thread. Why? Because otherwise running thousands of updates on them in real time gets kind of bottlenecked ;)

Comment: @TomTom Well, if you're doing thousands of updates on them in real time, you should probably be using double buffering anyway - and that can easily be done outside of the GUI thread.

Comment: @Luaan Except that my UI runs totally WPF. I use double buffering but as the windowsa re independent and talk to the backend anyway only via a thread decoupled message bus - there is ZERO overhead to have multiple UI threads. I can only assume trading applications are a little unusual in your world.

Comment: @TomTom I have trouble believing that you'd be bottlenecked on having a single-threaded GUI. I've done thousands of GUI updates per second with no trouble on a single thread, without major CPU usage. I have no idea how WPF's observables would hurt there (you're using those patterns, right?), but it doesn't sound likely they would have much impact. I'd expect much more impact from e.g. doing the `decimal.ToString()`'s on the GUI thread and stuff like that.

Comment: @L.B please give the link that answered question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The UI thread blocks so that the form is displayed but when you display it on another thread it just displays and then disappears immediately because it does not block.

Try this it starts a new message loop

```
private void Login()
{
    Application.Run(new MainPage());
}

private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread customInstallThread = new Thread(Login);
    customInstallThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
    customInstallThread.IsBackground = true;
    customInstallThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: You can't run `Close` in the parent form on the new thread (and it doesn't really make sense either - if you're killing the parent message loop, why bother creating a new one?). In any case, this is a very bad idea. Spawning new GUI threads to solve blocking long-time processing is going at the problem from exactly the wrong side. It's the background work that should be threaded, not the UI. There's just so many things that will go wrong if you do this.

Comment: @Luaan Check the edit? and one more thing why can not I run close in the parent form on the new thread? This code is working fine here...

Comment: Well, you shouldn't manipulate windows controls on different threads. It just gets tricky real fast. If you need to manipulate controls in a different thread, just use `Invoke` or equivalent.